# The session files aren't being filled and the php session variable says null. It used to work and then abruptly stopped

Tags: php, linux, session, rocky-os

I installed php8.3 and it worked for a few days. Sessions were working fine as was the session global variable. It puzzels the hell out of me as I know I changed nothing. I'm using rocky 9.2 I think but I have dnf upgraded. important logs are as follows in php-fpm.

[02-Dec-2023 23:46:09 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/html/bio.php:0
[02-Dec-2023 23:46:09 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "case_number" in /var/www/html/bio.php on>
[02-Dec-2023 23:46:09 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
httpd logs are as follows but there seems to be no log for today when the error occurred.

AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using localhost.localdomain. >
[Sat Dec 02 06:25:36.461940 2023] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 1483:tid 1483] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heart>
[Sat Dec 02 06:25:36.462782 2023] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1483:tid 1483] AH00489: Apache/2.4.57 (Rocky Linux) config>
[Sat Dec 02 06:25:36.462788 2023] [core:notice] [pid 1483:tid 1483] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREG>
[Sat Dec 02 17:53:29.577635 2023] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1483:tid 1483] AH00492: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gra>

Thank you for your time.

I checked the file permissions and checked the session file location. All good. I checked the session files that were created and they were created but were empty. I don't think my php.ini file has been changed and it used to work. To my knowledge no one else uses my computer unless someone has broken into my house, but that's unlikely. session start was used in bootstrap.php which is included at the top of the file. It just stopped working. It all worked and then it just stopped working.

Comment: Check your log for "Headers already sent" warnings. That will cause problems with the session cookie. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php for resolving it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately no headers were sent. This is not the problem. It's kind of like someone hacked me or something as there have been no changes to the file and it used to work perfectly. Does any one know what could be done to the operating system to make files not accomplish it's task?

Comment: @LukeLenacio can you provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example that you tried and is not working?

Comment: Thank you for all your help. It was really appreciated. Turns out late night coding isn't a very good idea. Seems I added a piece of code to circumvent other code for the admin user and forgot to add the sessions before the header. LOL a newbie like me shouldn't do more than eighteen hours of coding at a time. Sorry to waste your time.